# MS Access - Form Data Not Transferring to Table

Tags: ms-access-2016

I am a novice at this. Please be patient with me. I have a database for Home Inspections. I have a form called “Client_Details_frm” (form 1). This form includes a button “Add New” that opens a new form titled “Property_Details_frm” (form 2) that will take the [ClientID] from form 1 and populate [CID] on form 2. I can then fill in form 2 with the required details. Once form 2 is opened a new [PID] is assigned. Everything works fine until I click the “Save” button. This is a simple wizard produced cmd button.

For some reason, the Property ID [PID] is not transferring to the “Property_Details_tbl”. The error I receive when clicking “Save” states that Access can’t find a record in the table “Client_Details_tbl” with key matching field(s) “CID”. The [ClientID] is the PK in the client table and [CID] is a number field in the property details table.

If I’m understanding this correctly, I think I have two issues. 1) “Client_Details_tbl” is not updating before I open form 2 (which causes the error) and 2) the “Property_Details_tbl” can’t update because it has nothing to read due to the client table not updating. If this is the case, is a bit of VBA needed on both “Add New” (to essentially save the client form and update the table) and “Save” (to update the property table and close the property form)? If so, would you be so kind as to share some guidance on how to do this – meaning I don’t know enough VBA to ask it to do what I need it to do.

Comment: Hard to understand when we have to translate words into virtual description of you setup. How is "a new PID assigned" - is it an autonumber  field? Is the ClientID an Autonumber ID? Perhaps you just need to add `Me.Dirty = False`before opening the Property form. AGain - you don't say HOW you "take the [ClientID] from form 1 and populate [CID] on form 2"

Comment: If you have any code at all in your buttons please edit your question and insert code inside code tags